# How to start and stop (toggle) multiple threads in a infinite loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-c++

i am trying to find a solution to start and stop multiple threads in a infinite loops.

Each thread should be a seperated task and should run parallel. The threads are starting in a infinite loop and the thread itself got also in a infinite loop. Each loop should stop with the "GetKeyState" so i should be able to toggle the threads. But i am not able to start e.g. 2 Threads (Functions of the program), because the .join() is blocking the execution, and without the .join() the threading does not work.

Do you guys have a possible solution for this problem? The toggle start of one Thread is equal to the toggle stop of the infinite loop of the thread.

Here is some code i tried

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>


class KeyToggle {
public:
    KeyToggle(int key) :mKey(key), mActive(false) {}
    operator bool() {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(mKey)) {
            if (!mActive) {
                mActive = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
            mActive = false;
        return false;
    }
private:
    int mKey;
    bool mActive;
};

KeyToggle toggle(VK_NUMPAD1);
KeyToggle toggle2(VK_NUMPAD2);

void threadFunc() {
    while (!toggle) {
        std::cout << "Thread_1\n";
    }
}

void threadFunc2() {
    while (!toggle2) {
        std::cout << "Thread_2\n";
    }
}

int main()
{

    bool bToggle = false;
    bool bToggle2 = false;

    std::thread t1;
    std::thread t2;
    while (!GetKeyState(VK_NUMPAD0)) {

        if (toggle) {
            bToggle = !bToggle;

            if (bToggle) {
                std::thread t1(threadFunc);
                t1.join();
            }
        }

        if (toggle2) {
            bToggle2 = !bToggle2;

            if (bToggle2) {
                std::thread t2(threadFunc2);
                t2.join();
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: as i said if i don't use .join() i get a exception and are not able to start the threads, because it calls abort()

Comment: How about an [atomic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) boolean flag, that is "toggled" and checked by each thread. If the flag is clear the thread does what it's supposed to do, and if set the thread does nothing until waiting for the flag to become clear again.

Comment: no offense, but writing code merely to silence exceptions is not going to work on the long run. The `join` in this place is just non-sense.

Comment: As for the `join` problem, create a new loop at the end where you join the threads before the `main` function exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with the idea of @Someprogrammerdude

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<bool> aToggle1 = false;
std::atomic<bool> aToggle2 = false;
std::atomic<bool> aToggleStopAll = false;

class KeyToggle {
public:
    KeyToggle(int key) :mKey(key), mActive(false) {}
    operator bool() {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(mKey)) {
            if (!mActive) {
                mActive = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
            mActive = false;
        return false;
    }
private:
    int mKey;
    bool mActive;
};

KeyToggle toggle(VK_NUMPAD1);
KeyToggle toggle2(VK_NUMPAD2);

void threadFunc() {
    while(aToggleStopAll==false) 
    { 
       if(aToggle1) { std::cout << "Thread_1\n"; } 
    } 
}

void threadFunc2() {
    while(aToggleStopAll==false) 
    { 
       if(aToggle2) { std::cout << "Thread_2\n"; } 
    } 
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(threadFunc);
    std::thread t2(threadFunc2);

    while (!GetKeyState(VK_NUMPAD0)) {

        if (toggle) {
            aToggle1 = !aToggle1;
        }

        if (toggle2) {
            aToggle2 = !aToggle2;
        }

    }

    aToggleStopAll = true;

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

}
```

Comment: Could be simplified: `while(true) { if(aToggleStopAll) break; if(aToggle1) { std::cout << "Thread_x\n"; } }`

Comment: Could be simplified further: `while(aToggleStopAll==false) { if(aToggle1) { std::cout << "Thread_1\n"; } }` :-)